# Disable background chart on chartjs

Tags: angular, background, ionic2, chart.js, linechart

Hello everyone my problem is I want to remove the hashtag background of line chart. [image]

Is there any way to remove or disable it? I am using chartjs on my ionic 2 app.
Please help thank you

Heres my code to my line chart
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hashtag background is called `gridLines` and you can disable it like so:

```
type: 'line',
data: { ... },
gridLines: {
    display: false
}
```

Taken from http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#grid-line-configuration

Comment: Thank you it took me aged to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**For both axis**

option: {

**"scaleShowGridLines" : false**

};

**For X-axis :**

**scaleShowHorizontalLines: false**

**For Y-xais :**

**scaleShowVerticalLines: false**